# JAVA inheritance/polymorphism with 2 classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, eclipselink

I have *Incidents* in my system which can be *Accidents* or *Observations*. In the controllers, I have similar code workflows for both *Accidents* and *Observations*. I am facing issues understanding whether my problem is with java inheritance or polymorphism.

**Java inheritance ?**

- Parent - *Incident*
- Child - *Accident* and *Observation*

**Polymorphism?**
*Incident* ( **can be** *Accident* or *Observation*)

I tried to create an interface named Incident.java to cover both Accident and Observation and possibly remove code duplicates.  (This is shown at end below *Incident.java* ) But I am at a loss in understanding how to implemnt this inheritance.

*How do i define Incident.java? As a parent or as an interface of Accident/Observation ?.* 
**Please help me remove code duplicates in controller.java.**

***Code :*** 
**Controller.java**

```
    public class Controller extends ODataService {

        public void processIncidents(){    
            List<Accident> allAccidents = accidentDAO.getAll();
            for(Accident selectedAccident : allAccidents){
                createAlertsForAccident( selectedAccident); 
            }

            //possible change to incident? so we can remove this code?
            List<Observation> allObservations = observationDAO.getAll();
            for(Observation selectedObservation : allObservations){
                createAlertsForObservation( selectedObservation);
            }
        }

        public Observation createAlertsForObservation(Observation selectedObservation){         
            String notification ="INCIDENT #ID has been reported successfully by NAME.";

            Alert alert = new Alert(notification);
            selectedObservation.addAlert(alert);
            observationDAO.save(selectedObservation);
        }

//similar code as above for accident - duplicate
        public Observation createAlertsForAccident(Accident selectedAccident){
            String notification ="INCIDENT #ID has been reported successfully by NAME.";
    Alert alert = new Alert(notification);
            selectedAccident.addAlert(alert);
            accidentDAO.save(selectedAccident);
        }
    }
```

**Accident.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCIDENTS")
public class Accident implements IDBEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ACCIDENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String type;

    @Basic
    private String place;

    @Basic
    private int numberInjured;

    @Basic
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "OCCR_DT_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar occuredDateTime;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PEND_USR_ID")
    private String pendingWith;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PEND_USR_ROLE")
    private String pendingWithUserRole;

    @Basic
    @Column
    private String pendingWithReason;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "accident", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Injury.class)
    private List<Injury> injuries;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "accident", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Alert.class)
    private List<Alert> alerts;

    <-- getters and setters -- >
```

**Observation.java**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "OBSERVATIONS")
    public class Observation extends Incident implements IDBEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "OBS_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Basic
        private String type;

        @Basic
        private String place;

        @Basic
        private String category;

        @Basic
        private String subCategory;

        @Basic
        private String description;

        @Basic
        private String occuredDtTimeStr;

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "PEND_USR_ID")
        private String pendingWith;

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "PEND_USR_ROLE")
        private String pendingWithUserRole;

        @Basic
        @Column
        private String pendingWithReason;

        @Column(name = "OCCR_DT_TIME")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Calendar occuredDateTime;

        @Basic
        private boolean risk;

        @Basic
        private boolean hazard;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "observation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Alert.class)
        private List<Alert> alerts;
        <-- getters and setters -- >
```

**Incident.java ????**

```
public class Incident implements IDBEntity{
        ???
        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


        public Location getLocation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void setPendingWith(String actorName) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void setPendingWithUserRole(String actorRole) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void setPendingWithReason(String properNotificationWithReplacements) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

Comment: Interfaces are what your concrete classes will implement. In case of inheritance, you already have a concrete parent class,However choice is yours to go with either interface or class, My pick, I will be making **incident** as interface, because incident is not having any implementation of its own in your example.

Comment: Will passing **incident** to my createAlertClasses morph their behaviour according to the *accident* or *observation*? I tried to write the interface **incident.java** but how do i implement it?